# Configure Network Proxy Settings in Xcode for SVN Connection

Tags: svn, proxy, xcode3.2, xcode4.2

I tried to configure the SVN repository in my Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 but in both versions i am getting the error that "Options are missing:" and at the same time i tried to checkout the code from my svn through command line with the help of SVN with proper network proxy commands it is working.I used the below command:

`svn --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-host=proxy_url --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=port_no checkout https://repository_url foldername`

My question is how to achieve the same thing using the **xcode**?

Answer (score -1):

Do you use in Xcode an URL like "svn+ssh://yourName@repo.yourRepositoryUrl…"?

Comment: i tried that option also both in xcode 3 and Xcode 4 but i am facing the same problem